# angular clear input field does not work but clears using backspace

Tags: angular, typescript

When I tried to clear it by clicking the X button it does not clear and refresh it but when I tried using backspace to erase it clears the field and refresh . Why is that ? . I want it to clear when x button is clicked/

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="standard" fxFill>
                <mat-label style="font-size: 12px;">Filter users by name, company or title</mat-label>
                <input matInput #searchTransactionUserInput placeholder="" (keyup)="applyFilter($event)">
                <button mat-button *ngIf="searchTransactionUserInput" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"
                    (click)="clearSearch()">
                    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                </button>
            </mat-form-field>
```

#ts code

```
clearSearch() {
    console.log("clear")
    this.searchTransactionUserInput.nativeElement.value = '';
    this._transactionUserPageEvent();
  }
```

[image]

Comment: please share `clearSearch` function logic

Comment: Added Sir . please check

Comment: and how you are getting `searchTransactionUserInput` property in your TS?

Comment: @ViewChild('searchTransactionUserInput') searchTransactionUserInput: ElementRef;

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: do you mean the answer code didn;t work for you?

Comment: Actually, the problem is hard to detect because the code which you share should be working as expected https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fakebn?file=src/app/input-clearable-example.ts

Comment: not sure, I can't answer without looking at the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using ngModel is not a problem in your context, you could do this:

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="standard" fxFill>
                <mat-label style="font-size: 12px;">Filter users by name, company or title</mat-label>
                <input matInput [ngModel]="searchTransactionUserInput" placeholder="" (keyup)="applyFilter($event)">
                <button mat-button *ngIf="searchTransactionUserInput" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"
                    (click)="clearSearch()">
                    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                </button>
            </mat-form-field>
```

And in the *.component.ts:

```
searchTransactionUserInput = '';//string variable for ngModel instead of ViewChild and ElementRef

clearSearch(): void {
    this.searchTransactionUserInput = '';
    this._transactionUserPageEvent();
}
```

Comment: and the button does not clear the input fields

Comment: @JellynAng, I put the code of user2007130 in a stackblitz, see how we use `[ngModel]="search"` and `(ngModelChange)="search=$event;applyFilter($event)`

Comment: Do you have a link Sir ?